# C++ Pass member function pointer to inner-class

Tags: c++, c++11

Implementing operator[][] using proxy class. Works fine for single 2-dimensional data structure which can be accessed by some `double data(int row, in col)` method. However if I want to have few `data` methods I'd like to use pointer to member function which is stored in proxy inner-class `TPatternRow`:

```
class TLearnPattern
{
public:
    typedef int (TLearnPattern::* IndexFunction)(int);
    typedef double (TLearnPattern::* DataFunction)(int, int);

    TLearnPattern(TDataSource *source);

    class TPatternRow  ///< Proxy class to implement operator[][]
    {
    public:
        TPatternRow(TLearnPattern& source, int row, DataFunction func) :
            lp(source),
            i(row),
            data(func)
        {}
        double& operator[](int j)       { return (lp.*data)(i, j); }

    private:
        TLearnPattern& lp;
        DataFunction data = &TLearnPattern::in;
        int i;
    };

    TPatternRow operator [](int i) { return TPatternRow(*this, i, &TLearnPattern::in); }
    TPatternRow In(int i)  { return TPatternRow(*this, i, &TLearnPattern::in); }
    TPatternRow Out(int i) { return TPatternRow(*this, i, &TLearnPattern::out); }

    virtual double in(int row, int col) final;
    virtual double out(int row, int col) final;
}
```

How to syntactically correctly call following line?

`double& operator[](int j)       { return (lp.*data)(i, j); }`

Use std::bind? How to correctly bind this in `TPatternRow` constructor?

And some related question: does `bind` works fast enough comparing to just pointer to member function call?

Comment: And the error is? The called function doesn't return a double&, so operator[] can not return double&. You changed that in your "fix".

Comment: @manni66, ha, You are right. Problem was in `&`. Bind is unnecessary here, however strange `(lp.*data)(i, j)` construction works as `data` not a member of `TLearnPattern`. Why it works? Dot points not to a member here, but rather to class instance for pointer to member function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved like this:

```
double operator[](int j)
{
    auto dataFunc = std::bind(data, lp, _1, _2);
    return dataFunc(i, j);
}
```

or original without `&`:

```
double operator[](int j)       { return (lp.*data)(i, j); }
```